# how to extract numbers between square brackets?

Tags: python

I have a text file containing text like

```
index of cluster is 18585 points index are [18585, 14290, 18503, 7220, 6835, 10009,6615, 1269, 14161, 26545, 18140, 9292, 20355, 16401, 7713, 582, 1865, 17247, 26256, 19034, 7282, 1847, 19293, 16944, 27748, 29312,.... ] 
index of the cluster is 3014 points index are [ ....] and so on ..
```

I need to extract numbers between `"["` until `"]"` in every cluster in a single file. i tried to check if line has `"["` then get the numbers but didn't work right

```
import os 
f = open("cluster.txt","r")
for line in f.readlines():
    if "[" in line:
        print("true")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each line in the file you can use a regular expression to identify the data within the brackets. Then you can split the resulting string and use a list comprehension (or a map as shown here) to give you a list of all the numbers.

For example:

```
import re
line = '''index of cluster is 18585 points index are [18585, 14290, 18503, 7220, 6835, 10009,6615, 1269, 14161, 26545, 18140, 9292, 20355, 16401, 7713, 582, 1865, 17247, 26256, 19034, 7282, 1847, 19293, 16944, 27748, 29312]'''
a = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)
if a:
    nums = list(map(int, a[0].split(',')))
    print(nums)
```

**Output:**

```
[18585, 14290, 18503, 7220, 6835, 10009, 6615, 1269, 14161, 26545, 18140, 9292, 20355, 16401, 7713, 582, 1865, 17247, 26256, 19034, 7282, 1847, 19293, 16944, 27748, 29312]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i tried it now but got `if (a:= re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on `:=`

Comment: That's because you're using an out-of-date version of Python. You need 3.8+ or you can modify the code to do the assignment to *a* and the test in two steps. I've edited the code to support older Python versions

Comment: Thanks a lot i think i solved this issue 
`for line in f.readlines():
    a = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)` it worked

Comment: if i need to save every list in  a single file , please how can i start with this ?

Comment: @user You will probably want to build a list of lists

Comment: @LancelotduLac is there any downside of using `re.search` here ? I had the exact same pattern like you, just get access with `re.search(pattern,line).group(1).split(',')` with the same result.

Comment: @Rabinzel Consider what you would have to do if the search() didn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```py
f = open("cluster.txt","r")
for line in f.readlines():
    numbers_only = line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
    list_of_number_strings = numbers_only.split(',')
    list_of_numbers = [int(number) for number in list_of_number_strings]
```

With this, you will have the numbers converted to integers in the `list_of_numbers` list in the end. First, this splits the line to only get the part between `[` and `]` and then it just splits the remainder and converts them to integers. This assumes that each line will contain a list. If some lines would have a different format, you would need to add some additional logic for such cases.

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively do the following:

```
f = open("cluster.txt","r")
lst=[]

for line in f.readlines():
    lst += list(map(int, line.split("[").[1].split("]")[0].split(",")))

print(lst)
```

The list will get all lines of your file. The map just serves as transforming the recovered values into integers. You just have to convert the map to a list and append it to the main one.

Comment: This will work if the data in the file are exactly as expected. Blank lines or otherwise malformed lines will lead to IndexError